# Sometime setResult() in android is not deliver the right result code to another Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, onactivityresult

Here is my code,

```
 if (onApply) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        setResult(200, intent);
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Not every time, but sometimes I got result code 0 in onActivity result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there specific reason why you use `super.onBackPressed();` instead of `finish()`?

Comment: Because I got same error on the finish() also.

Comment: Perhaps the user is pressing the BACK button.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you may ignore the case that somewhere called finish() without invoking setResult().

BTW, RESULT_CANCELED = 0 is the default value because of setResult() has never been called.